# PHP get array items from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im trying to get array items from a database.
ive tried this soo far

```
$q1 = $sql->Query("SELECT * FROM `SYSTEM` WHERE `active`='1'");
$r1 = MySQL_fetch_Object($q1)
$randomheadline = array($r1->headline);
```

and $r1->headline does Return

```
"Something1", "Something2", "Something3", "Something4"
```

but when i try to echo out the array it Returns the Whole thing
this is how i echo my array

```
echo $randomheadline[2];
```

soo my question is how do i put all those array items from the database into that array?

Comment: You are making it an object, not an array, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php. Also consider updating to `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_assoc. I have included 4 Basic Examples. Hopefully you will find one of them helpfull. Example 1 and 2 might be in your best interest. Best of Luck!

```
    <?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "testPASS";
    $dbname = "testDB";
    $hostname = "localhost"; 

    //Connectd to Database
    $conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
      or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

    //Select Database
    $selected = mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn)
      or die("Could not select examples");

    //------------------------------ 
    //Example 1 - MYSQL_FETCH_ARRAY:
    //------------------------------
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `SYSTEM` WHERE `active`='1'");
    $headline_array  = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $headline_array [] = $row['headline'];
    }
    echo $headline_array[0];

    //------------------------------    
    //Example 2 - MYSQL_FETCH_ASSOC:
    //------------------------------
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `SYSTEM` WHERE `active`='1'");
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){
        $new_array[] = $row;
    }
    foreach($new_array as $array){
        echo $array['headline'];
    }

    //------------------------------
    //Example 3 - MYSQL_FETCH_ASSOC:
    //------------------------------
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `SYSTEM` WHERE `active`='1'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["headline"];
    echo $row[0];
    }

    //-------------------------------
    // Example 4 - MYSQL_FETCH_ARRAY
    //-------------------------------
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `SYSTEM` WHERE `active`='1'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['headline'];
    echo $row[0];
    }
?>
```